# Xcode 8 - user defined run time attributes not working for uiview border

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

In xcode 8 , in storyboard user defined attributes not working for adding border to a uiview[image]

Any idea , kindly share with me.

Comment: it's working on other xcode like 7.3.1 ?, have u check it ?

Comment: yes it was worked

Comment: and which color it is sowing right now as border color?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with layer.cornerRadius runtime attribute. It stopped working after updating Xcode 8.0.

[image]

Ticking "clip to Bounds" solved for me.

However it was working without tick in older versions!!!

Answer (score 0):

The user defined attribute of type Color uses UIColor, but for the layer.borderColor you need a CGColor. What you can do is create a file where you extend CALayer and create a setter method (setBorderColorFromUIColor) that obtains a UIColor. Inside the method you set the value of borderColor to the CGColor value of the UIColor parameter. Then change the keypath in the user attribute to layer.borderColorFromUIColor and run your program. It should work (at least it did to me).

```
@implementation CALayer (Additions)

- (void)setBorderColorFromUIColor:(UIColor *)color
{
  self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}

@end
```

Check [this](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/user-defined-runtime-attributes/) blog for more information